# Mapping specific JSON to Java object

Tags: java, json, mapping, fasterxml

I'm trying to map specific JSON to my Java Model class. And am having trouble mapping it to the Java object.

I'm using *fasterxml* (jackson) to map JSON to my Java Model class below - **CurrencyModel.java**. This JSON have '**[**' at the beginning which it probably means that it is an array. I cannot map it into my class, CurrencyModel.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class CurrencyModel {
    protected List<Currencies> currencies;
    protected List<CurrenciesRates> currenciesRates;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Currencies {
        @JsonProperty("table")
        private String table;

        @JsonProperty("no")
        private String no;

        @JsonProperty("effectiveDate")
        private String effectiveDate;

        @JsonProperty("rates")
        private ArrayList<CurrencyRatesModel> rates;
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class CurrenciesRates {
        @JsonProperty("currency")
        private String currency;

        @JsonProperty("code")
        private String code;

        @JsonProperty("mid")
        private String mid;
    }
}
```

And having JSON below in String variable

```
[
  {
    "table": "A",
    "no": "064/A/NBP/2013",
    "effectiveDate": "2013-04-02",
    "rates": [
      {
        "currency": "bat (Tajlandia)",
        "code": "THB",
        "mid": 0.1108
      },
      {
        "currency": "dolar amerykański",
        "code": "USD",
        "mid": 3.2552
      },
      {
        "currency": "dolar australijski",
        "code": "AUD",
        "mid": 3.4048
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to run this code using:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String output = "[{\"table\": \"A\", \"no\": \"064/A/NBP/2013\",\"effectiveDate\": \"2013-04-02\",\"rates\": [{\"currency\": \"bat (Tajlandia)\",\"code\": \"THB\",\"mid\": 0.1108},{\"currency\": \"dolar amerykański\",\"code\": \"USD\",\"mid\": 3.2552},{\"currency\": \"dolar australijski\",\"code\": \"AUD\",\"mid\": 3.4048}]}]";
List<CurrencyModel> currencyModelList = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(output, CurrencyModel.class));
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
System.out.println(currencyModelList.toArray());
```

which results in error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `` out of START_ARRAY token
```

Comment: *This JSON have '[' at the beginning which it probably means that it is an array.*: yes, indeed. So trying to map it to a class doesn't make much sense. You need to map it to an array or a collection. And the unique object inside the array has 4 attributes, one of which being an array. So, again, it doesn't match to your class, which has two attributes of type List.

Comment: How can I make array of my object inside my object CurrencyModel.java? Or how other way should I make it to work?

Comment: You already have two lists in CurrencyModel. You should have only one, since, in the JSON, only the `rates`attribute is an array. What you need to do is to fix your CurrencyModel class so that it matches with the unique object inside the JSON array, and then to deserialize the JSON array to a List<CurrendyModel> or a CurrencyModel[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see problem with your java class. I have executed your input json and come with mentioned below java class mapping.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class CurrencyModel {

    @JsonProperty("table")
    private String table;

    @JsonProperty("no")
    private String no;

    @JsonProperty("effectiveDate")
    private String effectiveDate;

    @JsonProperty("rates")
    private ArrayList<CurrenciesRates> rates;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class CurrenciesRates {
        @JsonProperty("currency")
        private String currency;

        @JsonProperty("code")
        private String code;

        @JsonProperty("mid")
        private String mid;
    }
}
```

And your main class,

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final String output = "[{\"table\": \"A\", \"no\": \"064/A/NBP/2013\",\"effectiveDate\": \"2013-04-02\",\"rates\": [{\"currency\": \"bat (Tajlandia)\",\"code\": \"THB\",\"mid\": 0.1108},{\"currency\": \"dolar amerykański\",\"code\": \"USD\",\"mid\": 3.2552},{\"currency\": \"dolar australijski\",\"code\": \"AUD\",\"mid\": 3.4048}]}]";

        List<CurrencyModel> myObjects = objectMapper.readValue(output, new TypeReference<List<CurrencyModel>>() {
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json contains list of object. So use `TypeReference`

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String output = "[{\"table\": \"A\", \"no\": \"064/A/NBP/2013\",\"effectiveDate\": \"2013-04-02\",\"rates\": [{\"currency\": \"bat (Tajlandia)\",\"code\": \"THB\",\"mid\": 0.1108},{\"currency\": \"dolar amerykański\",\"code\": \"USD\",\"mid\": 3.2552},{\"currency\": \"dolar australijski\",\"code\": \"AUD\",\"mid\": 3.4048}]}]";
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    List<CurrencyModel> currencyModelList = objectMapper.readValue(output, new TypeReference<List<CurrencyModel.Currencies>>(){});
    System.out.println(currencyModelList);
```